# Forced loading of unwanted php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, dropdown

I am using jquery ajax method to display a set of option values to a dropdown menu using my `title.php` file. But after loading the whole page, in chrome android browser it redirects to the `title.php`. Does anyone know what is the issue behind it?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$.ajax({

   method: 'post',

   url: 'Title.php',

     success: function(e){

      $(".name").html(e);

   }

});

});
```

I don't have issue in my PC (win10 chrome browser). I have experienced this issue in android chrome browser.
 https://ibb.co/hggLr8

Here is the screenshot of the error I am having. One more thing I noted is that this issue is not appearing while I am using incognito tab.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Does this issue only happen in Chrome on Android or can you replicate it ibn other browsers on other platforms? Also, are you loading jQuery? Also did you post this to jQuery UI tag?

Comment: hey @user3697054, edit your question to include the details you have provided in the comments. It will make it easier to solve.

Comment: Done bro.. thank you for your valuable advice.

Comment: Help me bro... pls help me